# Pointers linked list

Tags: c#

I have a linked list of stops (nodes). Each stop has multiple pieces of information. I want to add in the first items value for 'prevStop' in.

Currently I think something like this will work (if it was a pointer, is it a pointer?) but I'm sure their is a better way to do so?

```
public void AttachPrevToFirst()
{
    Stops temp = theList.First.Value;
    Stops temp2 = theList.Last.Value;
    temp.prevStop = temp2;
}
```

P.S. how would I print the data from the linked list?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the last node in the list before the first node in the list, you could use the `AddFirst()` method like so:

```
public void AttachPrevToFirst()
{
    theList.AddFirst(theList.Last);
    theList.RemoveLast();
}
```

However, perhaps you should use a `List<Stops>` collection instead if you need to be moving around nodes like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to make your list wrap around (make it circular) so that the last node's **next** property will reference the first node, and the first node's **previous** property will reference the last node - then you will need to extend (or work around) the LinkedList class as it is not circular by nature. Here are a couple of neat answers that should help you with this:

- [Using the ?? operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332084/138392)
- [Using extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2670199/138392)